# Why does the second while loop not get accessed at all after the first loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader

I created a nested while loop as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6KTS.png), however, after the first full loop is finished, the second while loop does not execute even though the condition inside the second while loop is still true. This could be an issue with `System.in`, but I tried commenting it out and it still did not loop again. What could be the issue here?

```
int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int p = 0;
        
        
        while(i < nStudents) {
            p = i+1;
            System.out.println("\nStudent " + p + "'s rankings: ");
            
            while(j < nSchools) {
                
                System.out.print("\nSchool " + toArrayList.get(j).getName() + ": ");
                String ranking = DisplayMenu.br.readLine();
                Array1.add(ranking);
                
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

I have also included an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKaAk.png), which shows what exactly happens here. For the second time looping through, it should print out the schools but it does not.

Comment: it's just the source code showing the two while loops and what they print. I will edit the question to show the code.

Comment: @PartialDifferentials please do provide compilable code!!!

Comment: @oleg.cherednik i would add it, but its 5 source files...

Comment: Please lean about the concept of a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set variable j to 0 after exiting the loop.

```
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int p = 0;
        int nStudents = 10;
        int nSchools = 4;            
        while (i < nStudents) {
            p = i + 1;
            System.out.println("\n Student " + p + "'s rankings: ");
            while(j<nSchools){
                System.out.print("\n School " + j+ " :");                   
                j++;
            }
            j=0; //// LIKE THIS
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this does not work is that, once the first full loop is finished (like you mentioned), `j` becomes greater than `nStudents` because of the increment you wrote `(j++;)`. It never gets set back to `0` or lower than `nStudents` for the second time it goes back into the `while` loop.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int p = 0;
    
while(i < nStudents) {
    p = i+1;
    System.out.println("\nStudent " + p + "'s rankings: ");
        
    while(j < nSchools) {
            
        System.out.print("\nSchool " + toArrayList.get(j).getName() + ": ");
        String ranking = DisplayMenu.br.readLine();
        Array1.add(ranking);
            
        j++;
    }
    //Set j less that nSchools here. One example is j = 0;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop can be used as well

```
int i = 0;
        int nSchools = 4;
        for(int nStudents = 10; nStudents > i; i++){
            System.out.println("\n Student " + i + "'s rankings: ");
            for(int j = 0; j < nSchools; j++){
                System.out.print("\n School " + j+ " :");
            }
            i++;
        }
```